# Magneto 1 - Product Collection Product Template/Component

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

Is it possible to create a template phtml file for the product collection > product?

I have different product collections, the different product collections all use the same style of "product card" if I add some additional functionality or text to the product card I have to change it on all the different product collection types.

Is there a method to template the bit inside the for each loop that spits out the individual products on a list?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create a module that rewrite the standard Product Block structure and distribute the product collection into an array by your needs.